# python how to return a row from csv file based on user input?

Tags: python

** i needed some help with returning a row from a csv file.My question was that im using an input for either last name or student id i want to bring back a row based on this.I figured out how to get the total records i just needed some help with displaying the rows.  If someone could provide the right direction to head in that would be helpful.**

```
for searchingByName or Id //logic

Example File:

Fname LastName StudentId
 john   jones    100
 billy  bob      101
```

Comment: Do you want to do that in Python?

Comment: Hi Kota, yes in python i was a little confused after i read each line how do i specifically bring back those rows from the csv file.

Comment: where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to load your csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
user_input = "bob"

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["fname"] == user_input:
        print row
```

Comment: thanks but im taking a python class right now. We have not learned what pandas is. Is there a way to do it without pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Example file:

```
Fname,LastName,StudentId
john,jones,100
billy,bob,101
```

I use comma to separate cells since it is CSV.

You can use `csv` library, which is in the python's standard library.
`pandas` is more handy, though.
Each `line` is a list of cell values. To match on the `j`-th column, use `line[j]`.

```
import csv

name_to_search = input("type last name:")

with open("example.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    # skip the first row, since it is header.
    header = next(reader)
    found = False
    for line in reader:
        if line[1] == name_to_search:
            print(line)
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        print(name_to_search, "not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn a CSV document into Python without using external libraries, you can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). The `sep` argument is where you specify the delimiter. Hopefully you have learned how to work with lists now. If your assignment doesn't explicitly prohibit you from using Pandas, you should definitely use Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

pandas is a nice library, but if you want to go pure python, you could try this:

```
id = '1'

lines = [line.strip('\n\r').split(',') for line in open("temp.csv")]

print('\t'.join(lines[0]))
for line in lines[1:]:
    if (line[0] == id):
        print('\t'.join(line))
```

where "temp.csv" is the csv file you're reading from, and you're searching by the first (0th) element in the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv.DictReader` to easily process CSV with header names:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    i = input('Input first name: ')
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Fname'] == i:
            print(' '.join(row.values()))
```

Sample input and output:

```
Input first name: billy
billy bob 101
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question, searchingbyname or by ID. below example will work for both kinds of user input.

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as stream:
    var = raw_input('Enter first_name or student_id: ')     #taking user input for fname or id
    reader = csv.DictReader(stream, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        if (row['Fname'] == var) or (row['StudentId'] == int(var)):    #matching with fname or id
            print(' '.join(row.values()))
```